# I need an http Post for this site

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

I have for many Days i could not make http post request for the following site

http://www.imei.sy/imei

I don't know the principle behind that. I tried to make the request using GuzzleHttp, and curl.

```
 $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.imei.sy/imei",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "UTF-8",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 20,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("_token:evsLRDom2AShHsioY5OyEB7cDU45opx8J0VLgqd2",//TgghCi5gkU6HODTyDwAWq0mvEyHC3ys8dXGskta1",
      "imei:000000000000000"),
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "postman-token: 6a987964-86b8-25db-71a5-7c47822ec59c"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

Comment: this site for testing the IMEI of any mobile wherther it's workable in my country or not.

Comment: I recreated the same request in Postman and received:```500 Internal Server Error

Time:509 ms

Size:4.95 KB
```. It established to a default Laravel 500 page.

Answer (score 0):

i can not reproduce the issue, when i run the code you provided, it executes the following POST request:

```
POST /imei HTTP/1.1
Host: www.imei.sy
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: UTF-8
cache-control: no-cache
postman-token: 6a987964-86b8-25db-71a5-7c47822ec59c
Content-Length: 295
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=------------------------4b99e3fabc390822

--------------------------4b99e3fabc390822
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="0"

_token:evsLRDom2AShHsioY5OyEB7cDU45opx8J0VLgqd2
--------------------------4b99e3fabc390822
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="1"

imei:000000000000000
--------------------------4b99e3fabc390822--
```

this is definitely a POST request in the `multipart/form-data`-format. (even tho the `Content-Type` header incorrectly claims that it's in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format, which makes servers unable to parse it properly.. but it's still a POST request nonetheless, it's just a severely malformed one.)

however note that code definitely won't be checking any IMEI code, because prior to checking a code, you must get a cookie and a CSRF token, the token won't work without the cookie and the cookie won't work without the token, but the token change for every cookie, and you can't hardcode it, but that's exactly what your code is trying to do,

your code won't work because:

- it never creates a cookie session (required to check an IMEI)
- it attempts to hardcode a CSRF token instead of fetching a dynamic token. (the CSRF token is tied to the cookie session.. which your code never creates in the first place.)

.. to check an IMEI here, first you have to enable cookie handling in curl, that can be done with CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, also `UTF-8` is not a valid transfer-encoding and makes no sense, instead do:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
// emptystring COOKIEFILE tells curl enable cookie-handling and save cookies in-ram
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>'',
// emptystring encoding tells curl to automatically handle compression with all built-in compression algorithms (usually "gzip" and "deflate"), it makes compressible transfers faster
    CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
));
```

next you have to fetch the page with a normal GET request, this will give curl the cookie needed to check an IMEI, and give curl the CSRF token needed to check an imei,

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>'http://www.imei.sy/imei',
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET=>1
));
$html=curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($html)){
    try{
        throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec() failed! ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch) );
    }finally{
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

after you got the cookie (which is handled automatically by curl), and the CSRF token in the HTML, you need to extract the token from the HTML, that can be done with DOMDocument and DOMXPath,

```
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$token=$xp->query("//input[@name='_token']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
```

and finally, now that you have both the session cookie and the CSRF token, you can do the IMEI lookup request,

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_POST=>1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
        '_token'=>$token,
        'imei'=>'999999999999999'
    ))
));
$html=curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($html)){
    try{
        throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec() failed! ".curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch) );
    }finally{
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

and to get the response from the HTML, one can again use DOMDocument,

```
$message=(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html))->getElementById("sts")->textContent;
var_dump($message);
```

which yields:

```
$ php wtf2.php
string(100) " مُعرف الجهاز المُدخل غير صالح، الرجاء التحقق من الرقم "
```

because 999999999999999 was not a valid IMEI code.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your efforts I'll check the code. and tell the result

Comment: Great Everything is working fine. I could not find any tutorial explain this full process